# The mt_rand() function of PHP returns only 2^31 different random numbers. How does it modify the normal Mersenne twister?

Tags: php, random, numbers, generator

I implemented Mersenne twister in java, and it can generate 32 bit uniformly distributed random numbers in the closed interval `[Integer.MIN_VALUE,Integer.MAX_VALUE]`.

When I call `mt_rand()` in `PHP`, it can generate `32 bit` uniformly distributed random numbers in this closed interval: `[0, Integer.MAX_VALUE]`. This interval is just the half!
It's still uniformly distributed, so it is good for generating random numbers.
But if I use the same seed for my implementation and for `mt_rand()`, I will get different results.

---

**Example one:**

```
mt_srand:=1000

mt_rand()

myseed:=1000

myrand()
```

`mt_rand` returns: `753084335`

`myrand()` returns:  `-1712525729`

---

**Example two:**(with different seed)

```
mt_srand:=10000

mt_rand()

myseed:=10000

myrand()
```

`mt_rand` returns: `983171632`

`myrand()` returns: `418336623`

---

What should I do to get the same values if I use the same seed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What makes you think it is possible to get the same random number sequence?

To get the same sequence you need to use an identical generator algorithm, down to every last detail. One of those details is the range of the output.

The easiest way to get identical output is to change your implementation to simply call `mt_rand`.

Another way is to compare your source code with the source code of the `mt_rand` used by PHP and verify that they don't differ.